# How can I modify the SwipeRefreshLayout swipe behavior when within a TabLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm using the android.support.design.widget.TabLayout within a SwipeRefreshLayout and I'm noticing that if my horizontal swipes have any slight downward change that the SwipeRefreshLayout is handled before the horizontal pager swipe. At the moment it's kind of hard to swipe the view pager because of this.

I'd like to modify the SwipeRefresh to respond only when the swipe is more vertical so that horizontal swiping is easier. Or maybe there is a better way to approach this?

This is my example app's activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the onCreate of my MainActivity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        mSwipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        mSwipe.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }
```

Comment: I haven't found any other apps that use a TabLayout within a SwipreRefreshLayout so perhaps it's a 'don't do that' scenario. But playing around with the Play Store app, you can only see the scroll view's over scroll indicator vs the horizontal swipe when the swipe is about 45%. I'd love to replicate that behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue with scrolling but there are several other little things to take into account. It's fairly easy to make the ViewPager and SwipreRefreshLayout to work better by disabling the SwipeRefreshLayout at the right time.

Essentially, if you listen to the ViewPager's OnScrollChange events you know when the user started the ViewPager scrolling and will get a SCROLL_STATE_IDLE when it's done scrolling. I was able to disable the refresh with setEnable(false) on the SwipeRefreshLayout when the state isn't idle. That stopped the refresh from taking over.

This will work fine if the contents of the ViewPagers pages do not scroll. But if they do you end up with another problem. Scrolling the view down to get to the top will be overridden by the SwipeRefreshLayout and you will only be able to scroll towards the bottom.

My solution for this new problem was to also disable the SwipeRefreshLayout unless the ScrollView was at the top. Depending on what your scroll-able view is, determining the top will be different so I'm not including any code for that.

The placement of the SwipeRefreshLayout also affects making this work correctly. If you have it outside of the Views in the ViewPager, and one page's scroll view is 'at the top' and you swipe to another page, you will have to check whether the new view is at the top as well. I did that in the same ViewPager.OnPageChaneListener.onPageScrollStateChaned.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mOnPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float v, int i1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);
            }
        }
    };
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(mOnPageChangeListener);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mViewPager != null) {
        mViewPager.removeOnPageChangeListener(mOnPageChangeListener);
    }
}
```